# Calculate coordinates of 3rd point (vertex) of a scalene triangle if angles and sides are known.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, triangulation

I am writing a program and I need to calculate the 3rd point of a triangle if the other two points, all sides and angles are known.

```
            A (6,14)
            ^
           / \
    14.14 /   \ 10.14
         /     \
        /       \
B (16,4)--------- C (x,y)
          10.98
```

A (6,14), B (16,4). Side AB is 14.14, AC is 10.14 and BC is 10.98
Angle A, B, C are 50, 45 and 85 degrees respectively...

I want to calculate the position of C. I don't know which formula to use for this. Actually i am performing triangluation. I am calculating the position of an incoming object (C).

Comment: You can use parametric equations for the lines with those angles. Then, just take the intersection. 

But I guess that there is some formula with trigonometric informations.

Comment: Thanks! I've thought of this but as you said there got to be some formula for this! Got to pass high school again!

Comment: @Sigur Yes you are right, trig is probably the way to go for this kind of problem.

Comment: **Hint** : One useful point will be, using distance formula. However it will be hard to use it but it will provide you at least one significant equation for(x,y). I think it would be $ x + y = -14.131 $

Comment: @Krat : The singular is "vertex"; the plural is "vertices".  I changed the title accordingly.

Comment: @mike: Sorry was too stressed.. Didn't check the grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help! I found the answer. The formula for which is given [here](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/circlesphere/) (Section: Intersection of two circles. It's not in the plot, but $d$ is the euclidean distance between the centers of the circles or $d=a+b$).

[image]

a = (r<sub>0</sub><sup>2</sup> - r<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + d<sup>2</sup> ) / (2d)

h = r<sub>0</sub> sinP<sub>0</sub> (or) r<sub>1</sub> sinP<sub>1</sub>

P<sub>2</sub> = P<sub>0</sub> + a ( P<sub>1</sub> - P<sub>0</sub> ) / d i.e., x<sub>2</sub> = x<sub>0</sub> + a (x<sub>1</sub> - x<sub>0</sub>) / d (and) y<sub>2</sub> = y<sub>0</sub> + a (y<sub>1</sub> - y<sub>0</sub>) / d

x<sub>3</sub> = x<sub>2</sub> ± h ( y<sub>1</sub> - y<sub>0</sub> ) / d

y<sub>3</sub> = y<sub>2</sub> ± h ( x<sub>1</sub> - x<sub>0</sub> ) / d

Comment: I struggled for a while to understand where the formula for the coordinates of $P_2$ came from. The key is to realize that $(P_1 - P_0)/d$ is just the unit vector that points in the direction of $a$ (The original vector is $v = (P_{1y} - P_{0y}, P_{1x} - P_{0x})$), so multiplying it by $a$ gives the coordinates for $P_2$.

Comment: And the key to the last step (the coordinates of $P_3$) is understanding that the unit vector along $h$ is perpendicular to the unit vector along $a$.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to take the middle point of $BC$ and duplicate it. Let me explain:

Consider $M=1/2(AB+AC)$. Then $C=2BM$. Now you have the vector and its norm, so is enough to solve an equation.

Comment: I think if we find the equation of lines BC and AC, we can find their point of intersection. If we drop a perpendicular CD to AB, what will be the slope of AC? Is it CD/AD??

Answer (score 0):

Take the following figure I made in paint:
[image: pic]

So basically, you want to find the lengths $AD$ and $DC$. So lets make the coordinates $(X_A,Y_A),(X_B,Y_B),(X_C,Y_C)$. The length $AO = |Y_A - Y_B|$ and $BO = |X_A - X_B|$. That means that $ \tan(\angle ABO) = \frac{AO}{BO} \leftrightarrow \angle ABO = \arctan(\frac{AO}{BO})$.
Because the angles of a triangle sum up to $180$ degrees, $\angle BAO = 180 - \angle ABO - 90 \leftrightarrow \angle BAO = 90 - \angle ABO$.
$\angle DAC = \angle BAC - \angle BAO$.
$\sin(\angle DAC) = \frac{DC}{AC} \longleftrightarrow DC = AC \sin(\angle DAC)$
$\cos(\angle DAC) = \frac{AD}{AC} \longleftrightarrow AD = AC \cos(\angle DAC)$
$X_C = X_A + DC$
$Y_C = Y_A + AD$
Now if you want two formulas with all the information compacted, you get:
$X_C = X_A + AC\sin(\angle BAC - 90 + \arctan(\frac{AO}{BO}))$
$Y_C = Y_A + AC\cos(\angle BAC - 90 + \arctan(\frac{AO}{BO}))$
Just for the record, the angles and lengths are good information to have, but because of the way trigonometric functions work, the coordinates $(x,y)$ might appear on the opposite side of line $AB$ in your example, while still fulfilling your constraints. You may have to add some if statements if you want it going in a certain direction.  Let me know if this equation works.

Comment: There got to be some easy way(s). One way as I have answered.. Another is to find the equations of lines AC and BC by using point-slope form `y-y1 = m(x-x1)`. If CD is perpendicular to AB, we can find the angles BCD and ACD. From these angles can we find the slopes of BC and AC?

Comment: @Krat CD and AB are not perpendicular (at least if you are referring to my image). Did you mean to say CD and AB?

Comment: not this image Sid! I am referring to the image I've drawn in the question..

Comment: @Krat What is point D on your picture?

Comment: D is a point on AB such that CD is perpendicular to AB.